# Glassfish Server 3.1.2 not starting from Netbeans 7.3

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

I am a newbie to Java EE, and was trying to get a Webapp's container security manager to work.

Im using:

GlassFish 3.1.2
Netbeans 7.3
Windows 8

After I checked the security manager on my GlassFish admin console I can't start the GlassFish server anymore.

I always get this:

```
access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getenv.GlassFish_Platform").
```

I am however able to start it from the console.
When i do so i can see the admin console and my jdbcRealm is not there anymore.

I tried finding the jvm option inside the domain.xml to delete as instructed in some other questions, but i don't have it set.

I did try running Netbeans as admin, also no luck there...

Any hints anyone?

Comment: The exact same versions of Netbeans and Glassfish run on my system without any problem, on Linux tho. Anyways, I remember I once had a similar problem when my glassfish directories were not accessible by Java. Did you check the folder's access rights?

Comment: Yes I do have all rights to the folder, till now only works once everytime i have to uninstall GlassFish and Netbeans then it works once again and blocks up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it Netbeans installs Glassfish in one folder but makes its own configuration folder on another path.

C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2.2\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml

i was editing that file, the one i needed was but in:

C:\Users\Andres\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3\config\GF3\domain1\config\domain.xm‌​l

so removed the security jvm-option and now it works again!

Comment: Maybe it's not important here, but I think it's worth to mention. I figured out, that Glassfish in 3.1.1 version doesn't like to be installed in path with spaces. I got really weird problems and exceptions while running server and deploying apps when it was installed in C:\Program Files path. When I moved it to path without spaces (for example C:\glassfish), all problems where gone with the wind. I thought that it would be useful to put this comment here for those who are looking.